# Xcode 4 gcc failure on Archive build: skips precompile step? (also after cleanup)

Tags: ios5, xcode4, pch

as many others i face the problem that my xcode (4.3.2) tells me:

```
 cc1obj: warning: /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foo-afikuaovoaeqhreaaaakpafseuuv/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/Foo_Prefix-guqixmujoiaaaacwjctfkrztxmbz/Foo_Prefix.pch.gch: created by a different GCC executable
 cc1obj: error: /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foo-afikuaovoaeqhreaaaakpafseuuv/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/Foo_Prefix-guqixmujoiaaaacwjctfkrztxmbz/Foo_Prefix.pch: No such file or directory
 cc1obj: error: one or more PCH files were found, but they were invalid
```

When i want to Debug my Application via inspector.
Building and running the app in development works fine, release also breaks it.

now the common tricks were to clean my build folder ( + alt key .. ) or deleting the derived-data folder entirey. both done, no effort.

any information i can provide the get some help? :)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound nuts, but had a similar thing (not quite the same) happen recently. I ended up actually deleting the Derived Data folder in finder -- after the clean --, and that resolved it for me.

Comment: @dhanke oups, i misread your comment in the question. Well, the plot thickens ... soon I fear I will need some sort of incantations book to work around Xcode's exquisite undocumented features.